# How to show #ERROR as Zero or as Nothing in matrix cell when groups and calculated field are based on switch-function in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, matrix, reporting-services

Imagine simple BI task:
We have two grouping columns and one calculated field.
like

```
select group1, group2, sum(sales) Sum_of_sales from dbo.table1
group by group1, group2
```

When for some combination of grouping columns there's no **ROW** in dataset - report shows me Empty. **It's ok.**

Now i'm building matrix with groups depending on parametrs. Some sort of programmatic matrix. User deciedes what to analyze by himself. He chooses X_dimension and Y_dimension and target CalculatedField

Grouping expression for first group now looks like

```
=Switch(
Parameters!param1.Value = "var1", Fields!groupingColumn1.Value,
Parameters!param1.Value = "var2", Fields!groupingColumn2.Value)
```

And for second group

```
=Switch(
Parameters!param2.Value = "var3", Fields!groupingColumn3.Value,
Parameters!param2.Value = "var4", Fields!groupingColumn4.Value)
```

With target value:

```
=Switch(
Parameters!param3.Value = "var5",  Count(Fields!sales_sum.Value),
Parameters!param3.Value = "var6",  Sum(Fields!sales_sum.Value)
)
```

When there are sales in combinations of groups - it's ok. It shows me exact value - like i would sum it with calculator. But when THERE'S NO DATA for some partition - it just raises error in that cell. And it seems like no way out. Pls help.

P.S. I tried all possible variants such as

```
iif(sum(...) is Nothing, 0 , sum(...))
sum(iif(value > 0 , value , 0))
```

and combination of them
i tried comparing with `ZERO`, `Nothing` , and checking `isNothing`

but i still get `error` in cell

Comment: can you show some sample data please? What I did to get around this is to "fill up" empty grouping values with 0 (or blanks) in the dataset (SQL) and then the matrix always has data.. not blanks.